# How to form a rails query to grab all the discussion posts a particular user has made?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, web, activerecord

I am using rails 5.0.0
I want to make a query that will let me display all the posts the current user has made. The two relevant tables I have are:

```
  create_table "discussions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "channel_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
         ....
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "username"
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end

  create_table "replies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "reply"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.integer  "discussion_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

and the relationships are as follows:

```
class Discussion < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :channel
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :replies, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :replies


class Reply < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :discussion
    belongs_to :user


class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable

  has_many :notifications, foreign_key: :recipient_id

  has_many :discussions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :channels, through: :discussions
```

in my discussions_controller.rb file i have the following line

```
@discussions = Discussion.includes(:users).where('users.id' => current_user).order('discussions.created_at desc')
```

and in my view file I have

```
<% @discussions.each do |discussion| %>

   ...

<% end %>
```

I expect there to be a few entries since I have created them, however no entries are displayed at all. This is what is printed in the terminal window

```
Processing by DiscussionsController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering discussions/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  SQL (0.5ms)  SELECT "discussions"."id" AS t0_r0, "discussions"."title" AS t0_r1, "discussions"."content" AS t0_r2, "discussions"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "discussions"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "discussions"."user_id" AS t0_r5, "discussions"."channel_id" AS t0_r6, "users"."id" AS t1_r0, "users"."email" AS t1_r1, "users"."encrypted_password" AS t1_r2, "users"."reset_password_token" AS t1_r3, "users"."reset_password_sent_at" AS t1_r4, "users"."remember_created_at" AS t1_r5, "users"."sign_in_count" AS t1_r6, "users"."current_sign_in_at" AS t1_r7, "users"."last_sign_in_at" AS t1_r8, "users"."current_sign_in_ip" AS t1_r9, "users"."last_sign_in_ip" AS t1_r10, "users"."confirmation_token" AS t1_r11, "users"."confirmed_at" AS t1_r12, "users"."confirmation_sent_at" AS t1_r13, "users"."unconfirmed_email" AS t1_r14, "users"."created_at" AS t1_r15, "users"."updated_at" AS t1_r16, "users"."username" AS t1_r17 FROM "discussions" LEFT OUTER JOIN "replies" ON "replies"."discussion_id" = "discussions"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "replies"."user_id" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY discussions.created_at desc
  Rendered shared/_discussions.html.erb (8.5ms)
  Channel Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "channels".* FROM "channels" ORDER BY created_at desc
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = ? AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered discussions/_sidebar.html.erb (34.1ms)
  Rendered discussions/index.html.erb within layouts/application (46.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 245ms (Views: 165.7ms | ActiveRecord: 6.7ms)
```

If I use
    @discussions = Discussion.includes(:users).order('discussions.created_at desc')

Then all the discussion posts display as they normally would as if the .includes statement was not there.
So, how can I change my query to list out the discussions made by the current user?

**Update** As per Shiko's comment, here is the output given with his input in the rails console

```
2.3.0 :001 > User.find(1).discussions
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Discussion Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "discussions".* FROM "discussions" WHERE "discussions"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Discussion id: 1, title: "Test", content: "alkjdflk slkfj ", created_at: "2018-04-08 22:40:06", updated_at: "2018-04-08 22:40:06", user_id: 1, channel_id: nil>, #<Discussion id: 2, title: "Fake Bakesale", content: "Come buy cookies", created_at: "2018-04-08 23:29:17", updated_at: "2018-04-08 23:29:17", user_id: 1, channel_id: 1>, #<Discussion id: 3, title: "Fake Bakesale", content: "Come buy cookies", created_at: "2018-04-08 23:30:18", updated_at: "2018-04-08 23:30:18", user_id: 1, channel_id: 1>, #<Discussion id: 4, title: "Meeting today", content: "Come to the meeting", created_at: "2018-04-08 23:35:59", updated_at: "2018-04-08 23:35:59", user_id: 1, channel_id: 1>, #<Discussion id: 5, title: "New post", content: "asdf ", created_at: "2018-04-15 21:50:20", updated_at: "2018-04-15 21:50:20", user_id: 1, channel_id: 2>]> 
2.3.0 :002 >
```

Comment: Your ActiveRecord query doesn't say anything about `Reply` or `replies` but your SQL is referencing the `replies` table. Are you sure you're looking at the right query?

Comment: I didn't think to check that but yes, I just verified that the user_id of my posts to correspond to 1. And yes, I'll update my post to inlcude the replies relationship. That could be affecting it

Comment: @muistooshort It must be the right query, but I think that is happening because of the way I set up my relationships? I just updated my post to include that information

Comment: Pass the **User ID** to below command in rails console and see if there are records or no : `User.find(10).discussions`

Comment: @shiko There are definitely records. I'll put the output in my post.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, if you run below command in rails console, you should get an below expected error :

```
@discussions = Discussion.includes(:users).where('users.id' => current_user).order('discussions.created_at desc')
```

Expected error:

> ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Discussion' to
>   association named 'users'; perhaps you misspelled it?

To fix this issue, you have to use `:user` instead of `:users` as below, simply because **each discussion belongs to one user** and not many :

```
@discussions = Discussion.includes(:user).where('users.id' => current_user).order('discussions.created_at desc')
```

There is a more a clean one way to get the current user discussions, using below:
**Controller:**
@user = User.find(curren_user_id)

**ERB file:**

```
<% @user.discussions.each do |discussion| %>
 .....
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
@discussions = Discussion.includes(:user).
    where(users: { id: current_user.id }).
    order("discussions.created_at desc")
```

If you don't need to reference the user attributes in your view, you can also do this, which avoids the join altogether:

```
@discussions = Discussion.
    where(user_id: current_user.id).order(created_at: :desc)
```